# django. adding a field to Form.errors in a custom clean() method

Tags: django-models, django-admin, validation

I have an Event model that I'd like to place the following validation rule on, in a custom `def clean(self):` method on the Model:

```
def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    if self.end_date is not None and self.start_date is not None:
        if self.end_date < self.start_date:
            raise ValidationError('Event end date should not occur before start date.')
```

Which works fine, except that I'd like to highlight the `self.end_date` field in the admin UI, by somehow nominating it as the field that has errors.  Otherwise I only get the error message that occurs at the top of the change form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) explain how to do this at the bottom.

**provided example:**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject and "help" not in subject:
            # We know these are not in self._errors now (see discussion
            # below).
            msg = u"Must put 'help' in subject when cc'ing yourself."
            self._errors["cc_myself"] = self.error_class([msg])
            self._errors["subject"] = self.error_class([msg])

            # These fields are no longer valid. Remove them from the
            # cleaned data.
            del cleaned_data["cc_myself"]
            del cleaned_data["subject"]

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

**for your code:**

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')

        if end_date and start_date:
            if end_date < start_date:
                msg = 'Event end date should not occur before start date.'
                self._errors['end_date'] = self.error_class([msg])
                del cleaned_data['end_date']
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Ah I see.  I applied my `clean()` method directly to the Model.   So this needs to occur on the form used by ModelAdmin?

Comment: @Daryl http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin might help you out. On another note, your answer acceptance is low. You might want to work on that if you want more help with your questions in general.

Comment: @Daryl http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects is another section that would be of interest to you if you want to do model level validation. `Model.clean_fields` especially.

Comment: I downvoted because when I saw direct access to `_errors` my eyes burned.

Answer (score 28):

From Django 1.7 you can directly add error to the particular field by using `add_error` method. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error)

`form.add_error('field_name', 'error_msg or ValidationError instance')`
If the `field_name` is `None` the error will be added to `non_field_errors`.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')

    if end_date and start_date:
        if end_date < start_date:
            self.add_error('end_date', 'Event end date should not occur before start date.')
            # You can use ValidationError as well
            # self.add_error('end_date', form.ValidationError('Event end date should not occur before start date.'))
            
    return cleaned_data
```