# Validate form with raise errors with django

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I'm trying to validate a form, user can't send contact info through the form, to achieve that, I have:

```
class ActualizarCotizacionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActualizarCotizacionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['proposal'].widget.attrs['rows'] = '4'
            self.fields['deliverable'].widget.attrs['rows'] = '4'

    class Meta():
        model = AffiliateQuote
        fields = ['proposal','deliverable','delivery_time','fee']


    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['proposal']
        if "311" in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You cant send phone numbers through the form")
        return data
```

And in template I have this line above the field `proposal`:     `{{form.proposal.errors.as_text}}`

Validation "311" that I had put here it's just for example, but with this, I cant get put it works, I write "311" in `proposal` field and the error does not display, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well put this validation in `clean_proposal` method, for example:

```
def clean_proposal(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['proposal']
        if "311" in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You cant send phone numbers through the form")
        return data
```

Comment: thanks, that's works.. If I have more fields, I have to make one clean_nameoffield for each field that I want to validate?

Comment: You can use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error , example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28474983/2696165